# How to change default vim colon commands?

Tags: vim

I know how to remap keys in .vimrc, but that's not what I want to do. I want to change a colon command; specifically, I want to change or remove `:X` (that's a capital "X"). I always type it when I'm trying to type `:x` (lowercase).

This has been driving me crazy for 15 years. My hands aren't going to stop making that typo 10 times a day. I've got to just change or remove that command.

Answer (score 1):

To re-mapping a command in `vim`:

```
:command <mapping command> <original command>
```

In your case:

```
:command X x
```

But don't do that.

`:X` is already a command in `vim`, it prompt for an encryption key.

If you feel it's hard to type `:x` correctly, use another shortcut for it, [ZZ](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#ZZ).

Comment: That's not an answer, sorry.

Comment: @felwithe: Well, I updated with the solution for remapping command, but it is still better to use the keyboard shortcut. You can't detect if you have override `vim` command default or not.

Comment: This game me an error: "E841: Reserved name, cannot be used for user defined command". The line I added to .vimrc was `:command X W`. I picked W because it's unused (according to vim whenever I type it).

Comment: @felwithe: you must use `command X W` in `.vimrc`, no colon. Note that this will map `:X` to `:W`, which is not an editor command.

Comment: That gives an error also. "E841: Reserved name, cannot be used for user defined command"